# Javascript jQuery Call function from parent to .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

on parent i replace div (id formhtml) with html (myhtml.html) using this function  :

```
$("#formhtml").html('<object data="myhtml.html" id="idform" width="100%" height="100%">');
```

inside myhtml.html, i have element

```
<input type="text"  id="t_id_textbox" >
```

i was tried call from function like this

```
$("#formhtml").html(alert(document.getElementById('t_id_textbox').value));
```

error :

```
TypeError: parent.document.getElementById(...) is null
```

please help how i get value of `t_id_textbox` from parent ?

Comment: I'll start with the obvious: `$("#formhtml").html(alert(...` doesn't make sense.

Comment: why are you putting an `alert` inside html? `alert` is a javascript function

Comment: If your textbox has an id, then getting its value is as simple as `$('#t_id_textbox').val()`.  But your error stems from the fact that you tried to call the `alert()` function from within html(), which only accepts text/html.

Comment: i put alert just for get value of 't_id_textbox'. i want use 't_id_textbox' value into my parent. i tried `alert($("#formhtml").html($('#idform').val()));` and still not have value from 't_id_textbox'

Comment: $.html() only accepts a string value.  You can't put code in there, unless it returns a string.

Comment: `alert($("#formhtml").html($('#idform').val()));` also won't work because the `$.html()` method returns an object, so the most you'll get is an alert that says [Object object].  Here's a tip.  Don't use alert() to debug your code.  Use Firefox Firebug, or Chrome Developer Tools.  You can put a breakpoint in your code exactly where you need the textbox value, then use the console to test out various Javascript commands.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious issues of putting an alert inside a `.html()` call, the issue is probably one of timing.

When you do this:

```
$("#formhtml").html('<object data="myhtml.html" id="idform" width="100%" height="100%">');
```

It creates an object and that object then loads that HTML file.  But it loads that content asynchronously (e.g. in the background just like images or iframes are loaded asynchronously) and your javascript continues to run.

So, if you immediately look for an element in that HTML, it is probably not finished loading yet so that element won't be there.

Since you have jQuery, you may want to use `.load()` instead and then you can use a completion function to know when the content has finished loading.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish since you haven't disclosed your HTML, but you could do something like this:

```
$("#formhtml").load("myhtml.html", function() {
    // in here the HTML will have been loaded
    alert($("#t_id_textbox").val());
});
```

Comment: That's incorrect that `$.html()` is an asynchronous process. It appends the value you give it immediately before continuing execution.  Look in the jQuery source code and see for yourself.  Furthermore, we have no idea what his order of execution is because he didn't post any code, only snippets of statements.

Comment: @TNguyen -`.html()` isn't an asynchronous process, but when the object tag that is created by it loads the `myhtml.html` file, that is an asynchronous process and that is where the content is that the OP is looking for.  This is just like if you dynamically insert an iframe tag or image tag and give it a `.src` property.  That content is loaded asynchronously.  The OP says that they create the object tag and then search for content in it.  The order is clear, but the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: how i load and get value from separate function ? 1 function for just for load and other function just for get a value ?

Comment: this my code on  [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/g28VD/6/) but still error i dont know to use jsfiddle

Comment: @Artron - which part of my sample code in my answer did you not understand?  It provides both of the things you asked for.

Comment: @jfriend00 , i understand clear your code, but i want it on separate function.i still confuse to split that function, one for just load on one function get...

Comment: @Artron - sorry, but I don't understand what else you need help with?  If you want to dynamically load HTML and immediately operate on it, your code has to wait until it has finished loading.  My code shows one way to do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 , thanks for helping. but if try using .load my page is not loaded into div [Using .load on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g28VD/9/)  [Using .html on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g28VD/7/)

Comment: @Artron - `.load()` for HTML content uses ajax so it is subject to the browser's [same-origin protections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) so you can only load content with it from the same domain as your page - thus you can't prototype this in jsFiddle.  Will have to use a test page on your actual domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#t_id_textbox").keyup(function(){
    $("#formhtml").html($('#t_id_textbox').val());
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/pkDLG/)**

Updated fiddle of OP with desired output:

**[ARTON's UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/g28VD/11/)**

Comment: better use `.keyup` to get exact value

Comment: What problem is this solving?

Comment: the problem is i was load html first then i call the the function... i have function to load `$("#formhtml").html('<object data="myhtml.html" id="idform" width="100%" height="100%">');` then other function will get the value inside the object

Comment: `function callform1(){
 $("#formhtml").html('<object data="myhtml.html" id="idform" width="100%" height="100%">');
};`

Comment: then call or get value from other function `function getvaluefromobject(){ //code to get value }`

Comment: this my code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/g28VD/6/) but still error i dont know to use jsfiddle

Comment: hey Artron and @jfriend00 - See the updated fiddle of Arton's http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/g28VD/11/